# .net c# - Notification between two MemoryCache

Tags: c#, .net, caching, notifications, memcached

I'm developing an 3-Tier Asp .Net application.

I have defined two memory caches, one in the Business Logic Layer/Data Access Layer, and the other one in the Presentation Layer.

[Descriptif schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfcMQ.jpg)

Below a simple example :

Cache in the Data Access Layer :

```
///DAL
public class DUserParams
{
    private static readonly object mutex = new object();
    private static DUserParams instance;

    private static ObjectCache cache;
    private const string cacheItemKey = "DAL_USER_PARAMS";

    private DUserParams()
    {
        cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    }

    public static DUserParams Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance != null)
            {
                return instance;
            }
            else
            {
                lock (mutex)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new DUserParams();                  
                    }

                    return instance;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<int, AppParameterInfos> GetAppParameters()
    {
        Dictionary<int, AppParameterInfos> res = null;

        CacheItem item = cache.GetCacheItem(cacheItemKey);
        if (item == null || item.Value == null)
        {
            res = GetAppParametersFromDataBase();

            if (res != null)
            {
                CacheItem cacheItem = new CacheItem(cacheItemKey, res, null);
                cache.Add(cacheItem, null);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            res = item.Value as Dictionary<int, AppParameterInfos>;
        }

        return res;
    }

    private Dictionary<int, AppParameterInfos> GetAppParametersFromDataBase()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Cache in the Business Logic Layer :

```
//BLL
public class UserParams
{
    private static readonly object _Mutex = new object();
    private static UserParams instance;

    private static ObjectCache cache;
    private const string cacheItemKey = "BLL_USER_PARAMS";

    private UserParams()
    {
        cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    }

    public static UserParams Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance != null)
            {
                return instance;
            }
            else
            {
                lock (_Mutex)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new UserParams();    
                    }

                    return instance;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<int, AppParameterInfos> GetAppParameters()
    {
        Dictionary<int, AppParameterInfos> res = null;

        CacheItem item = cache.GetCacheItem(cacheItemKey);
        if (item == null || item.Value == null)
        {
            res = DUserParams.Instance.GetAppParameters();
            if (res != null)
            {
                CacheItem cacheItem = new CacheItem(cacheItemKey, res, null);
                cache.Add(cacheItem, null);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            res = item.Value as Dictionary<int, AppParameterInfos>;
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

Cache in the Presentation Layer:

```
public partial class SystemParamsUtils
{
    private static ObjectCache cache;

    public SystemParamsUtils()
    {
        cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    }
```

What's is the best way to notify caches when one of them is changed ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are they both running in the same process? Or different processes? I assume you are using `MemoryCache` - is that correct? Can you include in your post where you declare and set both of the cache variables?

Comment: Thanks for you answer !

Yes im using MemoryCache and both caches are running in the same process. I included a simple example in my post.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use a single cache (i.e. `MemoryCache.Default`)?

Comment: thanks for your answer! 

I updated my post! i added a picture to better explain. Caches are in different processes. 

I have one cache in the presentation layer and the other one in the Business Logic Layer/Data Access Layer (MemoryCache.Default)

Comment: Earlier you said they were in the same process. You are sure they are in different processes? If they are in different processes, consider using https://github.com/MichaCo/CacheManager with Redis as the cache provider.